# ProcessingJS Create an Object which holds random number of items to draw flowers

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I am working on drawing a tulip flower in ProcessingJS.
I have code as below. The code will draw a tulip flower with a petal, and x, y, height is the preference for pedal location and height.

```js
`/*****************
*Tulip Object Type
******************/
var Tulip = function(x, y, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
};

Tulip.prototype.draw = function() {
    noStroke();
    fill(16, 122, 12);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 10, -this.height);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    // petals
    ellipse(this.x+5, this.y-this.height, 44, 44);
    triangle(this.x-16, this.y-this.height,
            this.x+20, this.y-this.height,
            this.x-20, this.y-this.height-31);
    triangle(this.x-14, this.y-this.height,
            this.x+24, this.y-this.height,
            this.x+3, this.y-this.height-39);
    triangle(this.x+-4, this.y-this.height,
            this.x+26, this.y-this.height,
            this.x+29, this.y-this.height-36);
};
`
```

Function to draw:

```js
void setup()
{
  size(400 , 400);
  background(125);
}

 var tulip = new Tulip (200, 200, 10);
 draw = function() {
    tulip.draw();

};
```

I want to draw random numbers of tulip flowers, with the value of x, y and height also randomly set respectively.

I'm thinking of using an array but after many tries still not working. How I create randomly flowers based on the Tulip object above?

Comment: Please be aware that Processing.js is no longer maintained - I discontinued it December 2018.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of random tulips:

```
int numTulips = random(10, 20); // between 10 and 20 tulips
Tulip[] tulips = new Tulip[numTulips];
for (int i = 0; i < numTulips; i++) {
  tulips[i] = new Tulip (random(30, 370), random(30, 370), random(10, 30));
}
```

Then draw the tulips

```
draw = function() {
   for (int i = 0; i < numTulips; i++) {
      tulips[i].draw();
    }
 };
```

Sample: https://codepen.io/bortao/pen/jOPobam

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of tulip. Use random to set length of that array. After that, loop throw the array and add tulip to array. Remember use random to make x, y & height of each tulip.

Now you have an array with random number of random tulip, you can do anything you want

Ex:

```
var Tulip = function(x, y, height) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.height = height;
};

var totalTulip = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1; // from 1 to 10
var tuplips = [];

for (var i = 0; i < totalTulip; i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1; // from 1 to 20;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1; // from 1 to 20;
    var h = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; // from 1 to 100;

    var tuplip = new Tulip(x, y, h);

    tuplips.push(tuplip);
}
```

P/s: it's Javascript :D